# ^ in package.json to get latest version of a library

Tags: package.json, semantic-versioning

Can I use caret ^ in package json for a library and expect it to pull the latest version. For eg "express": "^2.17.1", can the caret here used to pull the latest stable version which is lets say "4.17.1"

Comment: read the basic documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning that helps. It it won't jump major version own its own you have to do it. Obviously you have to handle the the fixes after that.

Comment: Thanks. I guess i got it wrong. ^ can only update the minor & patch version ranges